# Lowering the arrow in \overset{\rightharpoonup}{\calR}

Tags: formatting

I have the following:

```
\overset{\rightharpoonup}{\calR}
```

which produces

[image]

What I would like to do is to lower the `\rightharpoonup` so that it is closer to the `\calR` and doesn't cause a larger gap between lines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the bounding box of `\rightharpoonup`.

Some low level programming will help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hvec}[1]{{\mathpalette\hvec@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hvec@}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th#1{}_{\rightharpoonup}$\kern-\scriptspace\cr
      $\m@th#1#2$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\hvec{\mathcal{R}}_{\hvec{x}}$
% compare with
$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{\mathcal{R}}_{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{x}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a charm.